# No containers listed by command `yarn container -list <Application Attempt Id>`

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In Yarn Node Manager Web UI, total allocated containers of application attempt appattempt_1606741386263_0002_000001 is 4. But The containers list of the appattempt in web UI prints `No data available in table`.  
Also the command `yarn container -list  appattempt_1606741386263_0002_00000` doesn't list any container.

The version of hadoop is `3.1.4`. 
The linux distribution is Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I started the [timeline server](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html), and the `yarn container -list <Application Attempt Id>` is able to print the containers' information. But The web UI still prints `No data available in table`. The Timeline Server Web UI(port: 8188) is able to print the information of containers.